# How deserialize a json string of a byte[] in c++ unmanaged code a Json?

Tags: c#, c++, json, json.net, converters

In a unmanaged C++ program have to deserialize a json read by tcp from a server.

SERVER SIDE (made in C#) :

```
public class DUMMY
{
    public byte[] BinaryContent { get; set; }
}

... inside a http get controller ...
DUMMY d = new DUMMY();
d.BinaryContent = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00 }; // 0x00 is a sample, in real it contains a binary file
string sd = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
return sd;
```

CLIENT SIDE (made in C++ unmanaged) http-get read :

```
{ "BinaryContent" : "AAA=" }
```

The problem is how to deserialize it ?

How convert "AAA=" to a 0x0000 ?

2nd Examples : IF SERVER send { 0xFF, 0xFF } string received is "ERE=".

Comment: I highly doubt that 0xFF, 0xFF becomes ERE=. Pls check your 2nd example.

Comment: You are rights rustyx, 0xFF 0xFF becomes "//8=", value 0x11 0x11 becomes "ERE=". Thks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's Base64 encoding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

It's a way that can represent arbitrary bytes using only the ASCII character set.

You'll presumably want to find a library that can decode a Base64 string and give you back the bytes it represents. (Or it's possible to write that algorithm yourself, but I don't recommend it.)

Comment: **Thank you**, I find [cpp-base64 in github](https://github.com/ReneNyffenegger/cpp-base64) and I will try it.